# Creating new variables and then passing them to a function vs directly passing the evaluation

Tags: java, optimization

Below are 2 code snippets ->

**1**

```
Position bulletPosition = new Position(turretPosition);     
        float offsetX = turretSprite.getHeight() + (38 * MathUtils.cos(MathUtils.degreesToRadians * turretPosition.getAngle()) - 41);
        float offsetY = turretSprite.getWidth()/2 + (38 * MathUtils.sin(MathUtils.degreesToRadians * turretPosition.getAngle()));

        bulletPosition.addX(offsetX).addY(offsetY);
```

**2.**

```
Position bulletPosition = new Position(turretPosition);     

        bulletPosition
        .addX(turretSprite.getHeight() + (38 * MathUtils.cos(MathUtils.degreesToRadians * turretPosition.getAngle()) - 41))
        .addY(turretSprite.getWidth()/2 + (38 * MathUtils.sin(MathUtils.degreesToRadians * turretPosition.getAngle())));
```

In snippet 1, I am creating 2 float variables and then passing them as parameter to the addX and addY function.

In snippet 2, I am not creating the floats rather I am passing the evaluation as parameters.

Now lets say that this snippet is part of a function which is called every time user presses some key (i.e. very quickly).

Now my question is does that mean in **Snippet 1** we will keep creating new floats again and again and it won't happen in **Snippet 2**? Or both the scenarios are the same.

I like snippet one as it is cleaner but I want to know whether there is a difference between these 2 pieces of code? I always wonder this and thought of asking it today.

Comment: You have insanely fast users " every time user presses some key (i.e. very quickly)." - in most regular cases user input is considered to be "very rare" event (I doubt you get 1000 keystroke-per-second for example).

Comment: when you do `addX(expression)` it will evaluate the expression and put it kinda in an internal variable, and then use this variable as parameter.

Comment: Side notes: consider adding language tag (and mention compiler if it is C++), also check out [horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) by Eric Lippert to improve your "what is faster" question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: it seems to be Java, that syntax is not used in C++.

Comment: Should make no difference with any half-decent optimizing compiler. However, when in doubt measure some timings in a tight loop and see how it plays out in your specific environment/case.

Comment: It's Java. @AlexeiLevenkov keystrokes was an example. Let's pretend this happens in a for loop :/

Comment: The java virtual machine compiles the code at runtime. The resulting native code may actually be identical in both cases. It doesn't matter though. You won't notice any difference in practice either way.

Comment: Is not it strange to worry about whether float values will be optimized or not when you create new object right before that which is way slower than any float operations in any runtime?

Comment: I would make the floats `final`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I cannot ignore creating the objects but I can ignore creating the floats.

Comment: btw. the creation of that object may also be optimized away.

Comment: None of this matters at all unless you actually have a performance issue.  In that case, measure both and see which is better.

Comment: @i_am_jorf I know but it's nothing wrong in getting the knowledge.

Comment: @i_am_jorf curious to know why would you make them final?

Comment: @Sneh the link I've provided in first comment gives you all the knowledge you need to answer your question in a way that is useful to you. For evreyone else it is just entertaining discussion on whether there are compilers/runtime for Java that will optimize particular code and if there is any measurable difference .

Comment: (Also let me know if you need me to downvote your post too - I think you could have put more effort to compare these pieces of the code, but I'm not in soo negative mood :))

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov "I think you could have put more effort". I can make out you are intelligent but questioning someone's effort is more of a showing off that you know much more than others. And it's weird that you down vote people depending on your mood but not on quality of question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov If I was not putting effort, I would have been out drunk on new year eve rather than sitting late at 2:30 am and programming :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, the 2 local variables in Snippet 1 correspond to allocating more space on the stack and extra read-access from those stack locations for the function calls to `addX` and `addY`. Given an optimising compiler, the execution times of the two snippets are likely to be identical.

If the values of `offsetX` and `offsetY` are used more than once, you'll be ahead with Snippet 1 in theory, but again, an optimising compiler should cache them anyway.

Arguably, the main difference isn't in performance - it's in readability and, consequently, maintainability.

Comment: Thanks for not being a bully and giving a relevant up to mark answer :D